Cross sectional momentum vs time series momentum
What are the advantages/disadvantages of creating quantitative strategies using cross sectional momentum vs time series momentum?
From my perspective, time series momentum is a better indicator of continued increase/decrease as it indicates absolute performance of the stock.
Although, at the same time, perhaps cross sectional momentum is better because if a stock is outperforming/underperforming similar stocks in the market then I would think it more strongly be pushed by the market to continue in its same direction because of its uniqueness? In other words, if it performs better RELATIVE to other stocks then the market will take notice of that more strongly.
Also, is the profitability of both forms of momentum subject a result of things like redemption requests, post-earnings announcement drift, herding effect, etc?
I just learned about this so sorry if my question doesn't make sense, thank you!

You have answered your own question. You said, TSM is better if it is true and CSM is better if it is true. That is the right answer. Also TSM creates CSM. I can't imagine a portfolio created out of TSM doing much worse in CSM, if it does well in TSM

With all due respect this needs to be answered empirically, for a given market and a given (long) historical period, not with armchair speculation about "if this is true then it makes sense that this is also true, maybe" or "it seems to me that the market will take notice of this and decide to do that". We need "numbers on the table" as one of my former bosses used to say.

In "Advanced Portfolio Management", Paleologo is an advocate of CSM, I agree that the momentum of stocks relative to others is a much better indicator for the momentum factor.
Because if you just take TSM, it could be possible that all stocks are on the rise/fall at that point in time, which just identifies the momentum of the market and not the idiosyncratic (CSM) momentum.
UPDATE
I would like to quote this line from the book (section 5.2.3, page 62), which I think resolves this dilemma well -
"Momentum has a different meaning from trend-following, because it is based on relative performance, whereas
the latter is based on absolute performance".

Interesting - I agree with this. Thanks!
